# Linux 20.04 Dummy Output and Sound Card Not Detected

Tags: 20.04, alsa, soundcard

I am completely new to Linux. I have Dell Inspiron and I have Linux Ubuntu 20.4. And I’m just starting to set some things in order. The other day I got the right codecs to be able to **play** videos.

But now I don't have any sound...
And I'm struggling to find the solution. So with a lot of research  these are the facts -

- In Sound Settings it displays Dummy Output.
- I ran - `pacmd list -cards` - which gave me

  > 0 card(s) available ```
- So, it's not detecting a Sound Card
- I also ran - `alsamixer` and it returned

  > No such file or directory
- When I ran - `sudo aplay -l` and it returned

  > device_list:276: no soundcards found...

When I play a video with sound then go to settings under Output Device i can see that it is picking up the sound but its not coming through the speakers. Can anybody tell me the right steps to take please?

Comment: Check permissions as shown in https://askubuntu.com/q/1349221/66509 .

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem,
All I needed to do was add

options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0

to the end of the file /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

I still havent gotten my on-board speakers to work but now the soundcard shows up USB headphones and bluetooth headphones/speakers work fine.

If it doesnt you can also try adding

options snd-hda-intel model-generic  to the same file

It may help!

Comment: I ended up doing both lines of codes and on both accounts it said - permission denied. But I decided to have another look at the sound in my settings and instead of saying Dummy Output it said - Speaker -sof-hda-dsp. so I ested it and it worked on my on-board speakers!!! Thank you so so so much!! I'm sorry that you still don't have sound on your on-board speakers.