# Ubuntu Mini 20.04 doesn't give any sound

Tags: command-line, 20.04, sound, alsa, ubuntu-minimal

I have tried to get sound working on my ubuntu mini installation but it seems to be stuck at 0% or muted.

I have a base system installation with Xorg and Openbox. On top of that, Firefox (to see if the sound works).

I have tried to set it with `pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ 100%` but it seems to have no change.

> P.S. Installed from Ubuntu Mini 18.04 ISO and upgraded to 20.04

This is [what aumix looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ng93.png)

This is what [`sudo alsamixer` does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQoVP.png)

Doing the `amixer` command results in `amixer: Mixer attach default error: No such file or directory` doing that with sudo, gives me some [mixer output thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWYxr.png)

How could I fix this?

> edit:

Doing `alsactl init` and `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"` [shows these outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cueOB.png)

`sudo aplay -l` shows [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrqjm.png)

`pacmd` then `list-sinks` shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn00E.png)

Executing `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav` doesn't play anything but gives no errors, running it with `sudo` does however play the sound. This leads me to believe it's just a permissions issue

Comment: Since you apparently began from a Netboot (mini.iso) install, what leads you to believe that a complete audio stack is now installed? Or are you asking how to install it?

Comment: @user535733 is there a way to check if it's installed, and if not, how can I install it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which packages should be installed to have sound output working on minimal Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349221/which-packages-should-be-installed-to-have-sound-output-working-on-minimal-ubunt) ← check this Q&A, in my case `sudo apt install pulseaudio alsa-base alsa-utils vlc --no-install-recommends ; sudo usermod -a -G audio $USER` was enough. Installation from mini.iso is very flexible.

Comment: @N0rbert thank you, I have come to that conclusion as you were writing the answer.